# "Error in agg(x, ...) : agg can only support Column or character" error

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to aggregate a SparkR dataframe to get two summary variables,
the code I am trying to use is:

```
temp1_aggregate<- temp1 %>%
  groupBy("Week", "Store", "Brand", "Conversion_Factor", "Manufacturer", "Type") %>%
agg(Value=mean("Value"), Volume=mean("Volume"))
```

I have also tried summarise() instead of agg():

```
temp1_aggregate<- temp1 %>%
      groupBy("Week", "Store", "Brand", "Conversion_Factor", "Manufacturer", "Type") %>%
  SparkR::summarize(Value=mean("Value", na.rm=TRUE),Volume=mean("Volume", na.rm=TRUE))
```

Where Value and Volume are columns of numeric (double) type.

Both of these result in the same error:

```
Error in agg(x, ...) : agg can only support Column or character
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default("Value", na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I am quite confused by this as Value and Volume are both columns and are both numeric (I checked - though I can't share the data as it is proprietary).

I assume these errors are because the syntax is incorrect in some way (I tried to translate from dplyr to SparkR as I need to get it to work with spark dataframes), but I can't work out how.

Please can anyone advise on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `SparkR` mean implementation for `character` - it can only take columns, so as you can deduce from the warning message, `mean("Volume")` call is dispatched to `base::mean` and returns `NA`.

To make it work you have to use explicit `columns`

```
agg(Value = mean(column("Value")), Volume = mean(column("Volume")))
```

You can also replace `mean` with `avg` [`SparkR::avg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/avg.html)

```
agg(Value = avg(column("Value")), Volume = avg(column("Volume")))
```

which doesn't shade any built-in method, and would provide more meaningful error, if you passed plain `character`:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘avg’ for signature ‘"character"’